# Unable to check PostgreSQL Server status on Mac

Tags: macos, postgresql

On my Mac, I have a Postgres server installed at a specific location that I added to my .bash_profile. When I tried to start, I get some errors:

```
Joes-MacBook-Pro:~ postgres$ /Users/joe/Softwares/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/pg_ctl status
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.
```

I then tried to check the folder where Postgres is installed and here is what I see

```
drwxr-xr-x    3 joe    staff        102 Nov 23  2013 AngularJS
drwxr-xr-x    4 root   daemon       136 Apr 18 15:58 PostgreSQL
```

Here is what I have in my .bash_profile

```
export PGDATA=/Users/joe/Softwares/PostgreSQL/9.4/data
export PGSQL_HOME=/Users/joe/Softwares/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin
```

Should I change the user and group of the PostgreSQL folder from root to perhaps postgres?

Note: I'm not logged in as the postgres user. I'm trying to start postgres from another user called joe!

Comment: The error clearly says you haven't told it where PostgreSQL data directory is. You need to set it up

Comment: I did! In my .bash_profile, I have it set up!

Comment: try something like: `PGDATA="/usr/local/var/postgres" pg_ctl status`

Comment: Did you restart the shell? And you didn't show how you set it up.

Comment: I just edited my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why even after setting the PGDATA would fail! I had to do the following to get it work!

From the command line:

```
/Users/joe/Softwares/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/pg_ctl -D /Users/joe/Softwares/PostgreSQL/9.4/data status
```